# Can we add the custom MIME Type in Oracle Sql Developer client, and is there a tool for it?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The location in question is Tools> Preferences> External Editor in the Oracle SQL Developer. Currently, there are limited mime types in the External Editor option. I want to add some more like application/zip.

An image of the External Editor section:

[image: An image of the External Editor section]

Comment: Hi there. Mutual editing is a normal part of this platform; references to the guidelines are available upon request. Further edits are welcome to the question, but rolling back good edits is generally discouraged. Please ping me if you need further advice.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't add Mime types. All you can do is to set/change *editors* you'll use to work with types already provided in preferences.